# How much of a CPU die surface is taken by cache memory in modern microprocessors?

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory, cpu, cache, die

I am interested in how much of the surface of a modern or older CPU's are taken by cache memory ?

Are there any statistics regarding the size that cache memory takes in CPU dies of today ?

Are the schematics of the cpu's available to the public ? From those schematics can one see how much of the CPU surface is taken by various parts of the CPU ?

Comment: Some CPUs have huge caches and some has tiny CPU cores, and some both. It's not very uncommon if cache is bigger than the CPU core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detailed schematics are not available. However, third parties can decap the chip and take pictures ("die shot"), and Intel occasionally make nice maps in their publicity material:

[image]

The actual amount of cache depends heavily on exact part number - high-end ones have huge caches.

Comment: Nice picture. If the L3 is shared, I would expect each one of the cores to have its own L2 and L1

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami: Yes, this doesn't account for the per-core private L2 cache (256k on Intel "client" chips, 1MiB on Intel Skylake-server.)  Or the small fast L1d / L1i / uop-cache or branch-predictor "caches".  ([Why is the size of L1 cache smaller than that of the L2 cache in most of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549736) / [Which cache mapping technique is used in intel core i7 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092541))